# Matrix QR factorization algorithms

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

I've been trying to visualize QR decomposition in a step by step fashion, but I'm not getting expected results. I'm new to numpy so it'd be nice if any expert eye could spot what I might be missing:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import linalg

A = np.array([[12, -51, 4],  
[6, 167, -68],
[-4, 24, -41]])

#Givens

v = np.array([12, 6])

vnorm = np.linalg.norm(v)

W_12 = np.array([[v[0]/vnorm, v[1]/vnorm, 0],
               [-v[1]/vnorm,  v[0]/vnorm, 0],
               [0, 0, 1]])

W_12 * A #this should return a matrix such that [1,0] = 0

#gram-schmidt

A[:,0]

v =  np.linalg.norm(A[:,0]) * np.array([1, 0, 0])

u = (A[:,0] - v) 

u = u / np.linalg.norm(u)

W1 = np.eye(3) - 2 * np.outer(u, u.transpose())

W1 * A #this matrix's first column should look like [a, 0, 0]
```

any help clarifying the fact that this intermediate results don't show the properties that they are supposed to will be greatly received

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NumPy is designed to work with homogeneous multi-dimensional arrays, it is not specifically a *linear algebra* package. So by design, the `*` operator is *element-wise* multiplication, not the matrix product.

If you want to get the matrix product, there are a few ways:

1. You can create `np.matrix` objects, rather than `np.ndarray` objects, for which the `*` operator *is* the matrix product.
2. You can also use the `@` operator, as in `W_12 @ A`, which is the matrix product.
3. Or you can use `np.dot(W_12, A)` or `W_12.dot(A)`, which computes the dot product.

Any one of these, using the data you give, returns the following for Givens rotation:

```
>>> np.dot(W_12 A)[1, 0]
-2.2204460492503131e-16
```

And this for the Gram-Schmidt step:

```
>>> (W1.dot(A))[:, 0]
array([  1.40000000e+01,  -4.44089210e-16,   4.44089210e-16])
```